Update 3 level object
I want to update params of 3 levels of inner object with entityParameters:
List<Param> entityParameters

var filter = Builders<MachineObj>.Filter.Eq(x => x.MachineId, id);

filter &= Builders<MachineObj>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Machines, 
              inner => inner.MachineId == id2 && 
                       inner.Machines.Any(innerInner => innerInner.MachineId == id3
                                          && innerInner.Params.Any(ip => entityParameters.Any(ep => ep.ParamId == ip.ParamId)))
    
update = Builders<MachineObj>.Update.Combine(update, Builders<MachineObj>.Update
                      .Set(x => x.Machines.FirstMatchingElement().Machines.FirstMatchingElement().Params, entityParameters));


I think you need to explain your problem, and what is not working correctly in your code. Also, please do share the sample input and expected output document.

I can't do it with nested FirstMatchingElement() I needed to use a dynamic mongo string without types.
